# Close search results when an entry is selected in jquery typeahead

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery typeahead plugin by RunninngCoder (http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/documentation/).

I have tried figuring out what might be the cause of this problem. After selecting a search suggestion, there is a problem of the suggestions still being displayed.

I checked the issue on Github (https://github.com/running-coder/jquery-typeahead/issues/380) but I don't know how to resolve it. I keep on getting the error message **this.helper.namespace.call(...) is undefined...**.

Please any suggestions?

Thanks.

Version: 2.11.0

This is my JS:

```
$('.material-typeahead').typeahead({
    order: "asc",
    minLength: 1,
    // template: "{{display}} <small style='color:#999;'>{{group}}</small>",
    template: "<p>{{text}}</p>",
    dynamic: true,
    filter: false,
    hint: true,
    delay: 300,
    source: {
        product: {
            ajax: {
                type: "GET",
                url: "/products/s",
                path: "results",
                data: { q: "{{query}}" }
            }
        }
    },
    callback: {
        onInit: function() { console.log(this); },
        onSearch: function(node, query) {
            // console.log('you called the search');
            return query;
        },
        onClick: function(node, a, item, event) {
            // $(node[0]).val(item.text);
        },
        onSubmit(node, form, item, event) {
            return false;
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: Check the console for errors. There may be an issue in the logic which hides the option list which is preventing it from completing successfully.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan. 
That's true. I am always getting a 

this.helper.namespace.call(...) is undefined error message.

Any ideas on how to solve that?